# The minimal order value stops using of promo code in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a minimum order value of $10, and I want to give users a promo code with $30 credit. But when I enter the promo code to the cart, the subtotal shows $0, and the minimum order value does not allow the order to be completed.

For minimum order value I used this code in functions.php file:

```
function wc_minimum_order_amount()
{
// Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 10;

    if (WC()->cart->total < $minimum) {
        if (is_cart()) {
            wc_print_notice(
                sprintf(
                    'The minimum order value is %s Currently this order is %s',
                    wc_price($minimum),
                    wc_price(WC()->cart->total)
                ),
                'error'
            );
        } else {
            wc_add_notice(
                sprintf(
                    'The minimum order value is %s Currently this order is %s',
                    wc_price($minimum),
                    wc_price(WC()->cart->total)
                ),
                'error'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i understand your correctly you need to allow the customer to proceed the with the order regardless the amount of order even if the amount of the cart is below your minimum  order value?

Comment: @kashalo Yes, exactly.

Comment: can you just please post the hook you are using for this function, and i will fix this issue for you

Comment: Is this one?
`add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );`

Comment: yup that correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added an `if statement` to check if the specified coupon is applied then return and proceed the order normally if not check the minimum order value

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount');
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'wc_minimum_order_amount');

function wc_minimum_order_amount()
{
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 10;

    $coupon_code = 'test';  //Specific The Coupon Code to Check 
    if (in_array($coupon_code, WC()->cart->applied_coupons)) {
        return;
    }

    if (WC()->cart->total < $minimum) {
        if (is_cart()) {
            wc_print_notice(
                sprintf(
                    'The minimum order value is %s Currently this order is %s',
                    wc_price($minimum),
                    wc_price(WC()->cart->total)
                ),
                'error'
            );
        } else {
            wc_add_notice(
                sprintf(
                    'The minimum order value is %s Currently this order is %s',
                    wc_price($minimum),
                    wc_price(WC()->cart->total)
                ),
                'error'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

of course the code is tested, just placed in your `functions.php` and change the coupon code based on your requirement and you are good to go.